# Cannot render Here map on browser

Tags: here-api, tangram

I've migrated Here javascript libraries to be able to use api-key (because I can no longer generate appCode and appId on the developper portal). When I try to instanciate the map this way :

```
    let map = new H.Map(this.$('#map')[0], defaultLayers.raster.satellite.map);
```

I have the following error : `Tangram [error]: Scene.load() failed to load blob:http://localhost:4200/c3b06755-06b8-4a84-b888-9e5b574bb195: e[Symbol.iterator] is not a function TypeError: "e[Symbol.iterator] is not a function"`.

Ps: I am using Here javascript libraries in an Ember js project.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I'd say this part is wrong, `this.$('#map')[0]`. Did you mean to do `$('#map')[0]` instead?

Comment: Using ember js, `this.$('#map')[0]` and  `$('#map')[0]` do the same thing. For me the issue is due to WebGL. I created a web page with pure javascript and the same code worked (the one on ther developper guide) but on my emberjs project the code just breaks.

Comment: Is this online where I can see? Also,can you console.log(defaultLayers.raster.satellite.map) to ensure it works?

Comment: No it's only on my localhost. Yes `defaultLayers.raster.satellite.map` contains the correct data (I picked the code from Here documentation, so I presumethat  it's working). What I did also is trying the source code with native javascript and it worked. so the problem is incompatibility between NokiaHere 3.1 javascript core and Ember Js Framework :( . I will dig the problem later.